# Applying graph data structure to recipes in a game about combining elements

Tags: data-structures, combinations, graph-theory, combinatorics

I am designing a game where the player combines two ingredients to create a new element, which can then be used as an ingredient to create even more ingredients. It really seems that a graph structure would be a great way to interact with and analyze the recipes, however I cannot think of a structure which encodes all of the information.

some notes about the recipes I've designed:
they always involve two ingredients to create a product.
the two base ingredients could be the same ingredient twice
**a product can have many recipes**
a few recipes have more than one product

some example recipes to illustrate the rules:

```
bird + bird = egg
metal + bird = airplane
metal + air = airplane
metal + sky = airplane
bird + engine = airplane
**but** sky + bird =/= airplane
```

My first idea would be that products of a given ingredient would be directionally connected to the parent node, however this omits which of the other parent nodes is the specific one which combined to create the product.

Answer (score 0):

Since every product requires exactly two ingredients, the obvious data structure is a matrix.

Since the order of ingredients does not matter, you only need the upper triangle, including the leading diagonal.

You will need to add a product, called "nothing".

Arrange all the ingredients along the column heads AND the row heads.

Fill the cell where with the product of the column ingredient and the row ingredient, including "nothing" as required.

| X | metal | bird | air | sky | engine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| metal | N | airplane | airplane | airplane | N |
| bird |  | egg | N | N | airplane |
| air |  |  | N | N | N |
| sky |  |  |  | N | N |
| engine |  |  |  |  | N |

The question remains whether this is the "best" data structure.  Your question does not have enough details to answer.  It depends on what queries you want to pose to your data structure.

The matrix *could* be interpreted as the adjacency matrix of an undirected graph.  That would only be useful if you want to ask questions such as:  what is the shortest path from egg to airplane.  I find it difficult to imagine what such a question would mean, so I do not think a graph data structure is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative, more general representation of your recipes. Consider a weighted directed [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph), consisting of two distinct types of vertices: recipe vertices, and product vertices. An edge from a recipe to a product indicates the that recipe produces that product. An edge from a product to a recipe indicates that that particular recipe requires that product as an ingredient. The weight of an edge denotes the number that product consumed/produced in the recipe.

This is of course very general; you can have any number (even zero) of products as ingredients to some recipe, and a recipe can produce any number of products.

This graph will enable you to answer questions such as the shortest chain to produce a product (shortest path search), fewest total ingredients to produce a product, what products you can produce from some starting ingredients, etc.